# Converting html figure element to sql in python

Tags: python, html, sql

I'm trying to build a bot that crawls a notepad with a list of links and retrieves a table

```
import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    link="https://almashhadalsudani.com/economic-news/currency-prices-sudan/29061/"
    def info_grabber(link):
        try:
            source=requests.get(f'{link}')
        except:
            print("Unable to connect to GET service")
            return {'Error': '101'}
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")
        table_data=soup.find("figure","wp-block-table")
        prettyHTML = table_data.prettify()
        print(prettyHTML)
    info_grabber(link)
    #print(values)
```

The table element returned should then be added to the database and the process should be repeated till the list of links in the notepad is over.

So far this code outputs.

```
    <figure class="wp-block-table">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>
     <strong>
      العملة
     </strong>
    </th>
    <th>
     سعر الصرف
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     دولار امريكي
    </td>
    <td>
     370 جنيه
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     ريال سعودي
    </td>
    <td>
     95 جنيه
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     درهم اماراتي
    </td>
    <td>
     97 جنيه
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <strong>
      سعر الدولار الرسمي
     </strong>
    </td>
    <td>
     55.0000 جنيه
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     اليورو
    </td>
    <td>
     435 جنيه
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     الجنيه الاسترليني
    </td>
    <td>
     455 جنيه
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     ريال قطري
    </td>
    <td>
     96 جنيه
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     الجنيه المصري
    </td>
    <td>
     23 جنيه
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</figure>


***Repl Closed***
```

Is there a way to turn this answer into a database valid entry so that I could study this data or use it later?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc, SimplifiedMain
from simplified_scrapy.core.mysql_objstore import MysqlObjStore
import json

class CustomStore(MysqlObjStore):
    def saveObj(self, data):
        conn = None
        cur = None
        try:
            conn = self.connect()
            cur = conn.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute(
                    "insert into test(json) values(%s)",
                    (json.dumps(data), ))
                return conn.commit()
            except Exception as err:
                conn.rollback()
                print(err)
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
        finally:
            if (cur): cur.close()
            if (conn): conn.close()


class DemoSpider(Spider):
    name = 'almashhadalsudani'
    start_urls = [
        'https://almashhadalsudani.com/economic-news/currency-prices-sudan/29061/'
    ]
    # refresh_urls = True
    # Storing Obj with mysql
    obj_store = CustomStore(name, {
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'port': 3306,
        'user': 'root',
        'pwd': 'root',
        'dbName': 'test'
    })

    def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
        doc = SimplifiedDoc(html) # Parse
        data = doc.select('figure.wp-block-table>').getTable()
        return {"Data": {"table": data}}


SimplifiedMain.startThread(DemoSpider()) # Start
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from simplified_scrapy.core.mysql_objstore import MysqlObjStore
  File "C:\Users\PLAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\simplified_scrapy\core\mysql_objstore.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pymysql, json
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

***Repl Closed***

Comment: 2021-02-09 02:44:31 ('simplified-scrapy is running......',)
2021-02-09 02:44:31 ('https://almashhadalsudani.com/economic-news/currency-prices-sudan/29061/',)
waiting for new urls...
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)")

Thanks alot I think it's working.

Comment: database output is 5351 4c69 7465 2066 6f72 6d61 7420 3300
1000 0101 0040 2020 0000 0006 0000 0005
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002 0000 0004
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0006
002d fd72 0d0f f800 040e 0800 0f1b 0fcf
0e5a 0e08 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Comment: @Retro It seems that you have got the data and put it into the database. As for what data it is, you can get it here: data = doc.select('figure.wp-block-table>').getTable()

Comment: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)")

Comment: @Retro Change the configuration to your own MySQL service.